# $.ajax and JSONP. ParseError and Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

First of all, I've been looking for the answer to my problem in several topics and I couldn't find a solution that works with my code.

I'm trying to get the answer from a servlet, if I go to `http://XXXZZZ/Servlet/Login?login=pepe&pass=1234` I receive valid JSON as expected:

```
{"id":3,"login":"pepe","key":"0D1DBA4BE87E02D43E082F9AA1ECFDEB"}
```

But when I try the same with $.ajax, I get 2 errors.

```
$.ajax({
    type : "Get",
    url :"http://XXXZZZ/Servlet/Login",
    data :"login="+login+"&password="+pass,
    dataType :"jsonp",
    success : function(data){
    alert(data);},
    error : function(httpReq,status,exception){
    alert(status+" "+exception);
    }
});
```

First error (in the popup window):

```
parsererror Error: jQuery17104145435250829905_1336514329291 was not called
```

Second error (in the Chrome console):

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : Login 1
```

(And there is the JSON I'm waiting for).

P.S. I have to use dataType : "jsonp", because if I use "json" I also have problems with the Cross-Domain.

Comment: Whats the error function for ?

Comment: You cannot *force* JSONP. It has to be supported and return by the server. If it doesn't you are out of luck. If you have control over the server, make it support JSONP.

Comment: i'm also programming the server ;)

Comment: This may not affect this answer but may help other users- often times a parameter of the uri allows you to set the file format. If you are receiving this error, make sure that it is set to `format=jsonp`!

Answer (score 21):

If you are using jsonp then the syntax is wrong

You need to return

```
myJsonMethod({"id":3,"login":"pepe","key":"0D1DBA4BE87E02D43E082F9AA1ECFDEB"});
```

and also add to your ajax request options

```
jsonp: false,
jsonpCallback: "myJsonMethod"
```

so

```
$.ajax({
    type : "Get",
    url :"http://XXXZZZ/Servlet/Login",
    data :"login="+login+"&password="+pass,
    dataType :"jsonp",
    jsonp: false,
    jsonpCallback: "myJsonMethod",
    success : function(data){
        alert(data);},
    error : function(httpReq,status,exception){
        alert(status+" "+exception);
    }
});
```

(*and of-course fix the `success` as [@voyager](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10507372/128165) noted*)

Comment: So in the server i have to change 

    `static JSONObject Login(String login, String password) throws JSONException{`

to

    `static String Login(String login, String password){
        ...
        json.put("id", id);
        json.put("login", login);
        json.put("key", key);
        return("myJsonMethod("+json+");");`

Comment: @PabloPostigo, you can use the [`JSONPObject` class](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.5.3/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/util/JSONPObject.html)

Comment: had a similar problem. adding jsonp: false was what fixed things for me

Answer (score 11):

```
succes : function(data){
```

That's a typo:

```
success : function(data){
```

Comment: No, sorry i wrote it wrong here, in the code its written "success"

Answer (score 1):

First off you have a typo in your success parameter; you missed the ending s. Also, when you are performing a JSONP request you need to return your JSON information in JSONP format; which should include the callback token as part of the return string. A sample JSONP string would look likes this:

```
yourcallbacktoken({"id":3,"login":"pepe","key":"0D1DBA4BE87E02D43E082F9AA1ECFDEB"})
```

Take a look at this page for more information on the JSONP specifications: http://devlog.info/2010/03/10/cross-domain-ajax/