# Ajax JSONP Express parseError from Safari Extension

Tags: ajax, safari, express, jsonp

First, I've read many posts here but haven't found the issue in my own code, including this one [$.ajax and JSONP. ParseError and Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10507345/ajax-and-jsonp-parseerror-and-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token)

I'm building a Safari extension and need to post/get to my server and handle the response. Safari is throwing this error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'
```

and this message

```
"handle was not called"
```

where 'handle' is the callback in this Extension code:

```
var server="http://localhost:3001/api/login";
$.ajax({
       type : "GET",
       url :  server,
       data: {"something" : "else"}
       dataType: 'jsonp',
       jsonp:false,
       jsonpCallback: 'handle',
       success: function(data, text){
        var json = $.parseJSON(data);
        console.log(json)
       },
       error: function (request, status, error) {
        console.log(error );
       }  
});
```

and the Express.js (2.5.5) code is:

```
//in the config
app.set( "jsonp callback", true )

app.all('/', function(req, res, next){
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
  next();
});

app.get('/api/login', function(req, res){
res.json(
  {
    "success": {"that":"this"}
  }
);
});
```

NOTES: I've tried res.jsonp, setting content types, etc, with same response. I've learned a TON about CORS and Ajax in the process, but my eyes are clearly bleary. Clicking my heels three times hasn't helped either.

Clues? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By setting `dataType: 'jsonp'`, it will already parse the JSON for you. `jsonp: true` is incorrect. This combo should work:

#### JSONP

```
$.ajax({
   url : "http://localhost:3001/api/login",
   data: {"something" : "else"},
   dataType: 'jsonp',
   success: function(data){
     // It is already an object, don't parse it again.
     console.log(data)
   },
   error: function (request, status, error) {
     console.log(error );
   }  
});
```

with

```
app.get('/api/login', function(req, res){
  res.jsonp({
    "success": {"that":"this"}
  });
});

// Remove this:
app.set( "jsonp callback", true )
```

#### CORS browsers and JSON:

```
$.ajax({
   url : "http://localhost:3001/api/login",
   data: {"something" : "else"},
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function(data){
     // It is already an object, don't parse it again.
     console.log(data)
   },
   error: function (request, status, error) {
     console.log(error );
   }  
});
```

and

```
// This is 'app.use', not 'app.all'.
app.use('/', function(req, res, next){
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
  next();
});

app.get('/api/login', function(req, res){
  res.json({
    "success": {"that":"this"}
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks--tested your first example: that leads back to my other Q you commented on, got the double function again: 

jQuery19108954158783890307_1364399791627 && jQuery19108954158783890307_1364399791627({
  "success": {
    "that": "this"
  }
});

testing the others... (also, comma missing from the answer, will edit

Comment: the second example gives this error (this is an extension): XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3001/api/login?something=else. Origin http://www.example.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

I've set the extension permissions to allow all websites...
<key>Permissions</key>
 <dict>
  <key>Website Access</key>
  <dict>
   <key>Include Secure Pages</key>
   <true/>
   <key>Level</key>
   <string>All</string>
  </dict>
 </dict>

Comment: @bear I don't know much about Safari extensions unfortunately. Where is `example.com` coming from?

Comment: example.com is just my localhost. The extension grabs data from whatever site you're on currently and posts it back to that endpoint.

Comment: @bear Are you actually using 'example.com' in your code? That hostname is reserved.

Comment: I am not--just popped it in there for this. Using localhost.

Comment: @bear Oops! Found the issue. You are using `app.all` instead of `app.use`. `all` is equivalent to using `.get`, whereas `.use` binds middleware to run before handlers.

Comment: that's not it... really must be something in the extension. It might be that I should use the background page in the extension... @loganfsmyth

Comment: @bear Weird. I tried it out locally and after I changed that it worked for me. Can you confirm if you open up `/api/login` in your browser, you get the proper access-control headers? Maybe there is something more that the extension needs.

Comment: awesome tip, let me do that. I should've curled... but also am having some luck with running the script in the background page.

Comment: yes--works in the browser. Definitely an extension issue. Thanks! giving you props...@loganfsmyth

Comment: loganfsmyth now I'm able to just use straight json...using extension background page, which is treated as safe by Safari. I then have to communicate with the injected script through the safari api, which is the next bit of fun. You were a huge help though--really learned a lot so thanks.