# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have created a simple form to return a list of translation keys through the API. But it says `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :` Here is my sample code.

My form:

```
<form id="upload_form">
    <button type="submit">Ajax Request</button>
</form>
```

My ajax call:

```
$("#upload_form").submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
    url:'https://lokali.se/api/string/list',
 data:'api_token=641bc8455768b09589806c7d489640789cfb49e1&id=7509115157679787966292.60209031',
    dataType:'jsonp',
    type:'post',
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',

    success:function(response){
    console.log('hi');
    console.log(response);      
    },
});    
});
```

When I tested the API through *postman* it returns the *Success OK 200 response*
For reference please find the screenshot
[image: Postman]

My error is from here `{"response":{"status":"error","code":4049,"message":"Missing request parameter"}}` Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: could you please try like : instead of `data:api_token=641bc8455768b09`; try passing an object like `data: {api_token : '641bc84557...', id: '7509115...'}`

Comment: its because you use jsonp, why not just use json?, heres the same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10507345/ajax-and-jsonp-parseerror-and-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token

Comment: @vijayP `{api_token : '64...', id: '7509..'}` still same error :(

Comment: @MaanusIndov If I use json I am getting the cross domain error `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource`

Comment: witch language you use to write backend API? you can allways allow the origins, so no 3rd party application could not do requests 

**PHP:**  `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");`
* allows all, replace the * with your domain for more secure approach

Answer (score 0):

Can you try like the following ?

```js
$("#upload_form").submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
  var envelope = {};
  envelope.api_token = '641bc8455768b09589806c7d489640789cfb49e1';
  envelope.id='7509115157679787966292.60209031';
$.ajax({
    url:'https://lokali.se/api/string/list',
    data:envelope,
    dataType:'json',
    type:'post',
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    success:function(response){
    console.log('hi');
    console.log(response);      
    },
});    
});
```

Comment: If I add datatype as json it shows cross domain error as mentioned in the above comment

Comment: This is related to CORS. You can refer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/20442852/4848251

Answer (score 0):

check the json format, for example:

change:

```
data:envelope
```

to:

```
data : JSON.stringify(envelope)
```